# PHP Curl Connection Refused Localhost Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, self-signed-certificate

I have two local servers on localhost (configured as docker containers behind an nginx proxy), and I'd like to use CURL in server A to consume the API of server B. They are all using SSL with self-signed certificates (also already configured).

```
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . '/../' . getenv('SERVER_B_CA_CERT'));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, getenv('CURL_SSL_VERIFYPEER'));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, getenv('CURL_SSL_VERIFYHOST'));
```

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER are both set to false.

I'm getting a 'connection refused' (curl error code 7) message from PHP's curl library. There are no firewalls between my containers and my nginx proxy seems to be configured correctly. The server is up and listening because I've been able to connect to it using a web browser and a curl client.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "*   Trying 127.0.0.1..."
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* TCP_NODELAY set"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "*   Trying ::1..."
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* TCP_NODELAY set"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "*   Trying ::1..."
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* TCP_NODELAY set"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* Failed to connect to server-b.local.com port 443: Connection refused"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "* Closing connection 0"
php_1       | [05-Mar-2019 22:49:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 66 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: CURL ERROR = Failed to connect to server-b.local.com port 443: Connection refused, CODE = 7"
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software